# PostgreSQL count frequency of each keyword in keyword match

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Basically I'm checking to see if a column contains any of a list of keywords in an array

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE value ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['%bat%', '%cat%', ...])
```

Which works fine to give me the total count of columns with those keywords, but I also want to count how many times each of those keywords is hit. Ideally I would end up with

```
 Keyword   |   Count
---------------------
 bat       |     4
 cat       |    10
```

et cetera. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should create a table that has all of your keywords and then join that table to your big one using the condition. After that, you could aggregate by the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be better off with regular expressions for testing full words within a text:

```
with
  words(word) as (values ('bat'), ('cat'))

select w.word, count(*)
from words w
join table t on (t.value ~* ('\m'||w.word||'\M'))
group by w.word;
```

Replace `~*` with `~` if you need case-sensitive searches.

Comment: If I may there are 2 small mistakes in your otherwise great query: 1) the `with` part should be `values ('bat'), ('cat')` and 2) `count` should specifically count the table `t`, so `count(t.*)`